# Fixing System boot failure due to GRUB Error

Tags: linux, boot, partition, grub2

We have a Debian based system, which unpredictably goes in to non bootable mode.
Listed are the errors that usually occurs in the system.

```
1 > GRUB RESUE
2 > INTIRAMFS
3 > INIT SCRIPT FAILURE
```

Currently, we are looking out to point a reason for these errors. 
To start, I have collected the hard disk information of **GRUB RESUE** error machine

It would be great, If someone points the root cause for these errors.
What are the measures that should be taken to  avoid these errors.

**FDISK information:**

```
Disk /dev/sda: 320.1 GB, 320072933376 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 38913 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xc4bd0d2c

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *           1        3395    27261952   83  Linux
/dev/sda2            3395       28631   202706944   83  Linux
/dev/sda3           28631       38902    82503680    5  Extended
/dev/sda5           28631       38641    80404480   83  Linux
/dev/sda6           38641       38902     2095104   83  Linux
```

**parted information:**

```
Expected info:

Model: ATA ST320LT012-9WS14 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 320GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End     Size    Type      File system     Flags
 1      2097kB  27.9GB  27.9GB  primary   ext3            boot
 2      27.9GB  235GB   208GB   primary   ext3
 3      235GB   320GB   84.5GB  extended
 5      235GB   318GB   82.3GB  logical   ext3
 6      318GB   320GB   2145MB  logical   linux-swap(v1)

 Recieved info:
 Model: ATA ST9320325AS (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 320GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End     Size    Type      File system     Flags
 1      1049kB  27.9GB  27.9GB  primary   ** EXT3 MISSING **                boot
 2      27.9GB  235GB   208GB   primary   ext3
 3      235GB   320GB   84.5GB  extended
 5      235GB   318GB   82.3GB  logical   ext3
 6      318GB   320GB   2145MB  logical   linux-swap(v1)
```

case **GRUB RESCUE**
    In this when we try to mount our SDA partiton

```
mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/test  : It throws **Mount: you must specify filesystem type**

mount -t ext3 /dev/sda1 /mnt/test  : 
It throws **VFS: can't find ext3 filesystem on dev sda1**
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda1,
   missing codepage or helper program, or other error
   In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
   dmesg | tail  or so
```

Partition creation script details:

```
device="/dev/sda"
echo "Partition create process start for ${device}"
a=$(fdisk -l | grep ${device})
disk=`echo $a | awk '{print $3}' | sed 's/\:$//'`
if [[ "$disk" == 320* ]];then #For 320GB primary disk
    fdisk -u ${device} < hddSectorInfo.sh

    ###hdd Sector info###
    # n p 1 4096 54527999
    # n p 2 54530048 459943935
    # n e 3 459948032 624955391
    # n l 459952128 620761087
    # n l 620765184 624955391
    # a 1  w  q
    ####


fi
mkfs.ext3 -F ${device}1
mkfs.ext3 -F ${device}2
mkfs.ext3 -F ${device}5
mkswap ${device}6
swapon ${device}6
```

Also. request some pointers on partition creation..

```
        1. Making /boot as separate partition is a must ??
```

[Hard disk drive's smart info:](http://pastebin.com/ktBBCtXe)

Request pointers in fixing issue:

Comment: I guess you meant GRUB **Rescue** and not **Resue**.

Comment: Is this happening from time to time or you go into GRUB RESCUE whenever you start your machine? if it happens randomly check your grub init script, it may be refering to your root partition as /dev/sd"something". That is wrong, it should be refering to the UUID if you don't want to run into troubles, since BIOS may switch drives.

Comment: @YoMismo : No this happens very randomly. The system runs for more-than a month and suddenly this error  creeps. Yes you are right in GRUB it refers to SDA1. But in our case we do not any other physical drives in the machine.

Comment: Try using the UUID instead and see what happens. Have you run fdisk on the drive when you tried to mount it and it didn't? is it the drive you expected?, you could also have a bad superblock as the command's answer states. In that case follow this gide: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/recover-bad-superblock-from-corrupted-partition/

Comment: By the way, the physical and logical sector size you expect doesn't match. I thought 4096b per sector was only used in large drives (TB not GB) are you sure that is the correct physical sector size?

Comment: @YoMismo : you mean to point this right :: **Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes** So, you mean to say ideally it should match right.

Comment: It doesn't, but if that is the right physical size it should be aligned correctly. Check this http://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/Partition_Alignment

Comment: What does dmesg show when the system fails to boot?

Comment: **What errors are you getting?** At the very least, take a photo of the screen.

Comment: @Ernie when i connected the drive as secondary i got an UNC error from this hard disk .but when connected as primary .it directly goes to grub rescue mode.

Comment: @Gilles : It says **error:unknown filesystem ..Entering rescue mode ...grub rescue>**

Comment: Your comments don't make sense.  There's no reason to get a UNC error.  Please provide full, exact error messages.  Corresponding entries from `dmesg` would also be useful.